# How to use counter variable in if condition?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to use counter variable in IF condition..I tried but its not working.Please help me with correct code..
code is:

```
var ChForAtn=0;
if(arrayAtnd[ChForAtn]=="Name")
{                
    alert("Name");
    if(document.forms[7].ckbx'+ChForAtn+'.checked==true)
    {
        alert('Name added and checked also');
    }
    ChForAtn++;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var ChForAtn=0;  <--- Variable declared as 0
if(arrayAtnd[ChForAtn]=="Name")
{                
    alert("Name");
    if(document.forms[7].ckbx'+ChForAtn+'.checked==true) <-- You have your concatenation wrong.
    {
        alert('Name added and checked also');
    }
    ChForAtn++; <--- Variable incremented
}
```

First off, you should post your loop. The code snippet you posted doesn't contain a loop.

The only incremented variable you have in this code is reset at the top of the code, which doesn't make much sense for this fragment.

**EDIT**

The following won't work because you have your concatenation mixed up

```
document.forms[7].ckbx'+ChForAtn+'.checked==true
```

I'm not any too good with JS, but if you're trying to make a variable variable like in PHP, you'd have to use something like `eval()`. I know you can access it via `window[]` but this might not be possible in this case.

<strike>A solution with `eval()`</strike>

```
if (eval('document.forms[7].ckbx' + ChForAtn + '.checked') == true) {
  //code
}
```

**NOTE** There are good reasons **why you shouldn't use `eval()`**. Have a look here for more information : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Don.27t_use_eval.21

However, given your use case I don't really see a way around it. I would welcome alternative suggestions from other posters.

**EDIT2**

As @nickf points out in the comments, you can do the same thing by calling

```
if (document.forms[7]['ckbx' + ChForAtn].checked == true) {
   //code
}
```

**A cautionary tale for others, don't use eval() where avoidable :)**

Comment: @JohnP-I am not woorried of the loop or any flow of if condition..i just have some error in "if(document.forms[7].ckbx'+ChForAtn+'.checked==true)".... this condition checking...i want correction for that.

Comment: @vinay, your concatenation code was wrong. I've posted a solution that uses `eval()` use with discretion.

Comment: -1 for `eval`. Sorry, but using eval here is very bad advice.

Comment: Should be: `document.forms[7]['ckbx' + ChForAtn].checked`

Comment: @nickf, yup I know! I edited my post just as you were commenting. Would it be possible to access the dom elements via array? Or any other alternative?

Answer (score -1):

Use a for loop in the if condition.

Comment: @Faheem- there is something wrong in "if(document.forms[7].ckbx'+ChForAtn+'.checked==true)" this part..I want to correct that...Loop and all is later part

Comment: You don't want to loop inside the case, you want to loop outside of it. Otherwise the counter isn't being used

Comment: attius he want to use counter in side the if condition